# Issue while trying to insert the values into a temp table from a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, temporary-tables

Please help me on below .

I am trying to insert values into a temp table using the sql query. But I am facing below errors .

Please help me understand the mistakes.

Errors I am facing :

> Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
>   Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
>
> Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'use'.
>
> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 91 Cannot drop the table
>   '#BackupStatus', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

Query I have tried so far :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BackupStatus') IS NOT NULL 
DROP Table tempdb..#BackupStatus

create table tempdb..#BackupStatus(

Server_name VARCHAR(50),
Full_Backup_Status_Weekly VARCHAR(50),
Diff_Backup_Status_Daily VARCHAR(50),
Transaction_log_backup_Hourly VARCHAR(50))

--select * from #BackupStatus

insert into tempdb..#BackupStatus
(Server_name , Full_Backup_Status_Weekly,Diff_Backup_Status_Daily,Transaction_log_backup_Hourly)
--select Server_name , Full_Backup_Status_Weekly,Diff_Backup_Status_Daily,Transaction_log_backup_Hourly from
values
use msdb
go

WITH [MostRecentBackupStatus_CTE]
AS
(
    SELECT  bsfull.[server_name] ,
            bsfull.[database_name] ,
            bsfull.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_full_backup] ,
            bsdiff.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_diff_backup] ,
            bstlog.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_tran_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(dd, bsfull.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [days_since_full_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(dd, bsdiff.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [days_since_diff_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(hh, bstlog.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [hours_since_tranlog_backup] 

    FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] AS bsfull
            LEFT JOIN [msdb]..[backupset] AS bstlog ON bstlog.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                       AND bstlog.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                       AND bstlog.[type] = 'L'
                                                       AND bstlog.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT  MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                                                            FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                                                            WHERE   b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[type] = 'L') )
            LEFT JOIN [msdb]..[backupset] AS bsdiff ON bsdiff.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                       AND bsdiff.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                       AND bsdiff.[type] = 'I'
                                                       AND bsdiff.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT  MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                                                            FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                                                            WHERE   b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[type] = N'I') )
    WHERE   bsfull.[type] = N'D'
            AND bsfull.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                 FROM   [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                 WHERE  b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                        AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                        AND b2.[type] = N'D') )
            AND EXISTS ( SELECT [name]
                         FROM   [master].[sys].[databases]
                         WHERE  [name] = bsfull.[database_name] )
            AND bsfull.[database_name] NOT IN  (N'tempdb' , N'Master' ,N'Model' , N'MSDB')
)
SELECT  c.[server_name]  ,

       -- c.[database_name] ,
       -- d.[recovery_model_desc] ,
        --c.[last_full_backup] ,
        --c.[last_diff_backup] ,
        --c.[last_tran_backup] ,
        CASE 
            WHEN c.[days_since_full_backup] <= 7 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[days_since_full_backup] >= 7 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Full_Backup_Status_Weekly,
            CASE 
            WHEN c.[days_since_diff_backup] <= 1 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[days_since_diff_backup] >= 1 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Diff_Backup_Status_Daily,
        CASE 
            WHEN c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] <= 1 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] >= 1 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Transaction_log_backup_Hourly


       --c.[days_since_full_backup] ,
       -- c.[days_since_diff_backup] ,
       -- c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] 
        --c.[full_backup_location] ,
        --c.[diff_backup_location] ,
        --c.[tlog_backup_location]
FROM    [MostRecentBackupStatus_CTE] c
        INNER JOIN [master].[sys].[databases] d ON c.[database_name] = d.[name];


        DROP Table tempdb..#BackupStatus
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.

This is not an error, it's only information message.
It's caused by your code `insert into tempdb..#BackupStatus`.

You should use just `insert into #BackupStatus` (without specifying `tempdb`) because `#` already points to `tempdb`.

The error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'use'

is caused by

```
insert into tempdb..#BackupStatus
(Server_name , Full_Backup_Status_Weekly,Diff_Backup_Status_Daily,Transaction_log_backup_Hourly)
--select Server_name , Full_Backup_Status_Weekly,Diff_Backup_Status_Daily,Transaction_log_backup_Hourly from
values
use msdb
go
```

There are no values specified in `values` clause of your `insert` but instead there is `use`.

Just specify your values.

**UPDATE**

I reviewed your code and understood that you don't want to insert `values` but **you want to insert the result of select from msdb** using CTE,
so I rewrote your code, it should look like this:

```
use msdb
go


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BackupStatus') IS NOT NULL 
DROP Table #BackupStatus

create table #BackupStatus(

Server_name VARCHAR(50),
Full_Backup_Status_Weekly VARCHAR(50),
Diff_Backup_Status_Daily VARCHAR(50),
Transaction_log_backup_Hourly VARCHAR(50));

--select * from #BackupStatus

WITH [MostRecentBackupStatus_CTE]
AS
(
    SELECT  bsfull.[server_name] ,
            bsfull.[database_name] ,
            bsfull.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_full_backup] ,
            bsdiff.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_diff_backup] ,
            bstlog.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_tran_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(dd, bsfull.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [days_since_full_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(dd, bsdiff.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [days_since_diff_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(hh, bstlog.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [hours_since_tranlog_backup] 

    FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] AS bsfull
            LEFT JOIN [msdb]..[backupset] AS bstlog ON bstlog.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                       AND bstlog.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                       AND bstlog.[type] = 'L'
                                                       AND bstlog.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT  MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                                                            FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                                                            WHERE   b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[type] = 'L') )
            LEFT JOIN [msdb]..[backupset] AS bsdiff ON bsdiff.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                       AND bsdiff.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                       AND bsdiff.[type] = 'I'
                                                       AND bsdiff.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT  MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                                                            FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                                                            WHERE   b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[type] = N'I') )
    WHERE   bsfull.[type] = N'D'
            AND bsfull.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                 FROM   [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                 WHERE  b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                        AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                        AND b2.[type] = N'D') )
            AND EXISTS ( SELECT [name]
                         FROM   [master].[sys].[databases]
                         WHERE  [name] = bsfull.[database_name] )
            AND bsfull.[database_name] NOT IN  (N'tempdb' , N'Master' ,N'Model' , N'MSDB')
)


insert into #BackupStatus
(Server_name , Full_Backup_Status_Weekly,Diff_Backup_Status_Daily,Transaction_log_backup_Hourly)
SELECT  c.[server_name]  ,

       -- c.[database_name] ,
       -- d.[recovery_model_desc] ,
        --c.[last_full_backup] ,
        --c.[last_diff_backup] ,
        --c.[last_tran_backup] ,
        CASE 
            WHEN c.[days_since_full_backup] <= 7 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[days_since_full_backup] >= 7 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Full_Backup_Status_Weekly,
            CASE 
            WHEN c.[days_since_diff_backup] <= 1 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[days_since_diff_backup] >= 1 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Diff_Backup_Status_Daily,
        CASE 
            WHEN c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] <= 1 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] >= 1 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Transaction_log_backup_Hourly


       --c.[days_since_full_backup] ,
       -- c.[days_since_diff_backup] ,
       -- c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] 
        --c.[full_backup_location] ,
        --c.[diff_backup_location] ,
        --c.[tlog_backup_location]
FROM    [MostRecentBackupStatus_CTE] c
        INNER JOIN [master].[sys].[databases] d ON c.[database_name] = d.[name];

select * from #BackupStatus;

DROP Table #BackupStatus;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply insert straight into the # table, can't you?

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM dbo.table1
```

Then you don't need to worry about creating the able first (and having to modify its definition if you modify your subsequent SELECT statement)

Here's a re-write of your code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#BackupStatus') IS NOT NULL 
DROP Table #BackupStatus

use msdb
go

WITH [MostRecentBackupStatus_CTE]
AS
(
    SELECT  bsfull.[server_name] ,
            bsfull.[database_name] ,
            bsfull.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_full_backup] ,
            bsdiff.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_diff_backup] ,
            bstlog.[backup_finish_date] AS [last_tran_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(dd, bsfull.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [days_since_full_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(dd, bsdiff.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [days_since_diff_backup] ,
            DATEDIFF(hh, bstlog.[backup_finish_date], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS [hours_since_tranlog_backup] 

    FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] AS bsfull
            LEFT JOIN [msdb]..[backupset] AS bstlog ON bstlog.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                       AND bstlog.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                       AND bstlog.[type] = 'L'
                                                       AND bstlog.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT  MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                                                            FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                                                            WHERE   b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[type] = 'L') )
            LEFT JOIN [msdb]..[backupset] AS bsdiff ON bsdiff.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                       AND bsdiff.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                       AND bsdiff.[type] = 'I'
                                                       AND bsdiff.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT  MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                                                            FROM    [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                                                            WHERE   b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                                                                    AND b2.[type] = N'I') )
    WHERE   bsfull.[type] = N'D'
            AND bsfull.[backup_finish_date] = ( (SELECT MAX([backup_finish_date])
                                                 FROM   [msdb]..[backupset] b2
                                                 WHERE  b2.[database_name] = bsfull.[database_name]
                                                        AND b2.[server_name] = bsfull.[server_name]
                                                        AND b2.[type] = N'D') )
            AND EXISTS ( SELECT [name]
                         FROM   [master].[sys].[databases]
                         WHERE  [name] = bsfull.[database_name] )
            AND bsfull.[database_name] NOT IN  (N'tempdb' , N'Master' ,N'Model' , N'MSDB')
)
SELECT  c.[server_name]  ,

       -- c.[database_name] ,
       -- d.[recovery_model_desc] ,
        --c.[last_full_backup] ,
        --c.[last_diff_backup] ,
        --c.[last_tran_backup] ,
        CASE 
            WHEN c.[days_since_full_backup] <= 7 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[days_since_full_backup] >= 7 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Full_Backup_Status_Weekly,
            CASE 
            WHEN c.[days_since_diff_backup] <= 1 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[days_since_diff_backup] >= 1 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Diff_Backup_Status_Daily,
        CASE 
            WHEN c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] <= 1 THEN 'Success'
            WHEN c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] >= 1 THEN 'Failed'
        ELSE NULL END AS Transaction_log_backup_Hourly


       --c.[days_since_full_backup] ,
       -- c.[days_since_diff_backup] ,
       -- c.[hours_since_tranlog_backup] 
        --c.[full_backup_location] ,
        --c.[diff_backup_location] ,
        --c.[tlog_backup_location]
into #BackupStatus
FROM    [MostRecentBackupStatus_CTE] c
        INNER JOIN [master].[sys].[databases] d ON c.[database_name] = d.[name];

        SELECT * FROM #BackupStatus
        DROP Table #BackupStatus
```

In SQL Server 2016, you can also use
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #BackupStatus
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/

I hope this helps,

B